# (silverlight) Unable to start program "http://localhost:58397/checkTestPage.aspx"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, visual-web-developer

I am using Microsoft visual web developer 2010 Express. (silverlight)(c# and xml). Few minutes before it was working properly but i wanted to make some changes in registry on this path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Silverlight\`  `To enable in-browser trusted applications`  but after i deleted those changes.

After it my code compiles error free but it gives message http://prntscr.com/34q9ae and moreover it opens internet expolrer but it hangs the IExplorer and it don't show inside the the GUI that i created using xml.

How to come out of this problem. How this problem arised and can be solved ? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messing with the registry keys (like AllowElevatedTrustAppsInBrowser etc.) should not affect localhost operations. In any case, you mention you added and then deleted the keys. So the Silverlight registry entry should have the 3 default keys.. Default, Version & UpdateConsentMode.

Try quitting Visual Studio including the "IIS Web Express" server on the task bar.
Also, try exiting all the IExplorer.exe processes from the task manager.

Now open Visual Studio and try again.

Comment: Raja Babu , Thanks a lot bro i uninstalled and installed SP-1 and and Silverlight tools and it worked fine.